# Invalid directory name Spyder Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I've been trying to figure out how to solve this issue.

```
 File "<ipython-input-27-0b2b3f4a72cc>", line 5, in <module>
    X_BW, y_BW = setAnnotation(path, 1, nclusters = clusters, clf = clf)

  File "<ipython-input-26-6f5632d48ec5>", line 211, in setAnnotation
    for file in os.listdir(newPath):

NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] Invalid directory name: 'C:/img/soft/leftshoe10.jpg'
```

I'm using this fuction to set an annotation for all the images I send through the path.

```
def setAnnotation(path, representation, nclusters = None, clf = None, centroids = None, gmm = None, alpha = None):
    c = 0
    for folder in os.listdir(path):
        newPath = os.path.join(path, folder).replace("\\", "/")
        annotation = os.path.basename(newPath)
        print(newPath)
        for file in os.listdir(newPath):
            if file.endswith(".jpg"):
                if c == 0:
                    if representation == 1:
                        X = getBOF(os.path.join(newPath, file), clf, nclusters)
                        print("PRUEBA CON BOW")
                    elif representation == 2:
                        X = getVLAD(os.path.join(newPath, file), clf, centroids, alpha)
                        print("PRUEBA CON VLAD")
                    elif representation == 3:
                        X = getFV(os.path.join(newPath, file), gmm)
                        y = annotation
                        c = c + 1
                        print("PRUEBA CON FV")
                else:
                    if representation == 1:
                        X = np.vstack((X, getBOF(os.path.join(newPath, file), clf, nclusters)))
                        print("PRUEBA CON BOW")
                    elif representation == 2:
                        X = np.vstack((X, getVLAD(os.path.join(newPath, file), clf, centroids, alpha)))
                        print("PRUEBA CON VLAD")
                    elif representation == 3:
                        X = np.vstack((X, getFV(os.path.join(newPath, file), gmm)))
                        print("PRUEBA CON FV")
                y = np.concatenate((y, annotation), axis = None)
    print("Anotación finalizada.")
    return(X,y)
```

Here I set the path to use with the function above.

```
path = "C:/img/soft"
```

And here I call the `setAnnotation()` function described before.

```
X_BW, y_BW = setAnnotation(path, 1, nclusters = clusters, clf = clf)
```

The error points to the following line in the `setAnnotation()` function:

```
X = getVLAD(os.path.join(newPath, file), clf, centroids, alpha)
```

I What I've search around is to use a `.replace("\\", "/")` after `os.path.join` in the `setAnnotation()` function. But I don't know why is pointing to line 211 since I'm using `1` as `representation` parameter, which must enter just in the first conditional.

¿Any idea?

Comment: You appear to be trying to iterate over all files in the directory `C:/img/soft/leftshoe10.jpg`, which is not a directory. It's a JPEG.

Comment: The error is clear. You're trying to treat an image as a directory.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above. I solved the issue modifing the path. `C:/img/`. So the function in charge of reading the files just starts searching for sub-folders after `/img` and files ended with `.jpg`, avoiding to try to put the JPG file as a sub-folder.